# Function for turning TimeStamps and Counter Values to a rate?

Tags: r, time

Are there any libraries in R with a function to take something like:

```
   CounterDateTime CounterValue
1 2012-01-25 17:09:04        25052
2 2012-01-25 17:09:06        25054
3 2012-01-25 17:09:07        25054
4 2012-01-25 17:09:08        25055
5 2012-01-25 17:09:09        25055
6 2012-01-25 17:09:10        25055
```

And convert the `CounterValue` column to a per second rate? Ideally it will work with the irregular time in my example.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but are you just talking about subtracting the first value from each column and then dividing? (Obv converting the POSIX column to secs along the way?)

Comment: @joran: Yes, basically I am wondering if there is something like `z = data.frame(c2$CounterDateTime[-1], diff(c2$CounterValue))` out there but far less stupid :-P Rather not reinvent the wheel, likely in a crappy way, if there is something smarter out there.

Comment: Ok. I'm not aware of anything, but that doesn't necessarily mean much. My first inclination with something this simple, though, would just be to write it myself.